# JavaScript Cross-Origin image Sharing on localhost! What to do?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, localhost, sharing

OK so, i've been stuck for a long time now on this.
I've read all the other quetions and comments about this but i haven't got any further...

I am working on a JavaScript project in Aptana Stundio 3. When i open my index.html file 
in my main folder i get this:

**Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.**
(Using the latest version of Chrome)

But only if i open the html file in my folder. When i run it on Apanta, it works just fine.

My project is never going to run on any server... It's just a game that i want to share with other people, but on their **localhost**.

I've read things about CORS and stuff but i just don't get it.
I know i have to change the header of my file so that i can get access to my sources, but i dont know **HOW?!**

What do i do? Not in general, but in my case.

Hope i get this soon.

Comment: what you are loading ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018118/chrome-js-cross-origin-image-load-denied

Comment: Are you using a server like apache to serve the html file? or are you just opening the file from your computer directly in the browser?

Comment: I think you are going to have to run it off a local server, or reduce the security settings in Chrome (not a good idea).

Comment: No im not using a server, and yes im opening it in my browser

Comment: And how do i run it off a server so that other people don't have to do something...just opening the file?

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers, security settings prevent pages running from the file system from using JavaScript to access other files on the file system. This is a good defence against attacks based around emailing an HTML document as an attachment to a victim.

If you want to access other files, then access all of them over HTTP.

Comment: Ok but how do i make this? Do i have to change the source of the images to something like 'http://' or what?

Comment: Yes. They need to be hosted on a web server

Comment: How do i let the browser know, that my HMTL page isn't 'public'?

Comment: But i cant run them on a server...

Comment: Then you can't run them.

Comment: :(( isent there a way to turn this off??

Comment: Possibly … but it would be on a per-browser basis … and it would be unreasonable to ask people to turn off security features in their browsers to run your software.

Comment: right... so how do i host a html file on a server without the user having to set it up?

Comment: You set up the server, then you give the user the URL.