# Cross-origin image load denied on a local image with THREE.js on Chrome

Tags: javascript, three.js, cors

I'm using THREE.js and I get this error in the developer console:

```
Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.
```

when I open my script with Chrome.
The code looks like this:

```
var particle_system_material = new THREE.ParticleSystemMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/circle.png"),
});
```

So as you can guess, the:

```
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("images/circle.png");
```

is the problem.
With Firefox it works very well.

I've read the tips in the following links :
[Chrome, three.js: Cross-origin image load denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018118/chrome-js-cross-origin-image-load-denied),
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally,
https://www.google.fr/search?q=Access-Control-Allow-Origin

I also realized the commands given:

> **Start Chrome executable with a command line flag:**
>
> chrome --allow-file-access-from-files

nothing works and I'm going crazy. It is just an image on my hard drive with HTML and JS files, no server, no "origin".

Answer (score 2):

Are you running a local server, or are you just opening the html file?

Most likely, running a localhost server will fix this issue. [Mamp](http://www.mamp.info/de/index.html) / [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) are super easy to use.

If that doesn't work, you can do something drastic like `chrome --disable-web-security`

Comment: It is just a HTML file. I tried with Wamp, but it doesn't change anything :/ concerning `chrome --disable-web-security`, I saw somewhere that it could cause problems with some malware on the internet, no ?

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't recommend using it all the time. Just use it when you're working on this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that if you start chrome with the disable web security flag, you must first **shut down all other instances of chrome** in order for it to work as you expect.