# How to display a locally selected image in three.js?

Tags: image, three.js, webgl

I always get a cross-origin-error. how can I circumvent this, or better yet, fix it?
I need the user to be able to pic a local image and let it be displayed in a PlaneGeometry.

my code:

```
this.reader.readAsDataURL(file);
this.reader.onloadend = function( ev ) {
var file = ev.target.result,
//geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 0.1),
geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 1, 2),
texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(file),
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture }),
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.name = "Marker" + mesh.id;
mesh.rotation.x = 90 * ( Math.PI / 180 );
Editor.addObject(mesh);
console.log(Editor.scene.children);
SignalHub.signals.updateScene.dispatch();
SignalHub.signals.markerAdded.dispatch();
```

The geometry shows up but it's blank!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use an img.

```
var image = document.createElement( 'img' );
image.src = dataurl;

var texture = new THREE.Texture( image );
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

See [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1305).

**Option 2**

Where is the html server from? If it is a local htm file, then you could instead serve it from a web server on the local machine (e.g. IIS / apache).

Whether the server is local or remote, you can upload the image to your web server when they have selected it and use a URL to retrieve it from the web server. This will satisfy the cross-origin policies.

**Option 3**

1. Convert the image into Base64 text
2. Store it in an external Javascript file
3. Link it to your project page
4. Load it into your texture

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17144989/746754) (SO answer) and [here](http://tp69.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/cors-bypass/) (details off-site).

**Option 4**

Create a shortcut for the browser such as:

```
c:// ... /chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

**Option 5**

Use the `.crossOrigin = ''` property. It was not working, but I think it is now fixed. See [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/779) and [here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras/ImageUtils).

Answer (score 1):

I made this example: http://develoteca.com/EjerciosOnline/Exampleplane/, you can load a local image 
Greetings.

Comment: great, I will check it when I get home

Answer (score 0):

To add a image in background use these 3 lines of code

```
const textureImage = '../images/star.jpg';
const textureloader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
scene.background = textureloader.load(textureImage)
```

To add 6 - different images in background use these 5 lines of code

```
const star = '../images/star.jpeg'
const nebula = '../images/nebula.jpeg'

const cubeTextLoader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()
scene.background = 
cubeTextLoader.load([nebula,star,nebula,nebula,nebula,nebula,])
```