# How can I load a local image in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, base64

I am trying to put an image on an object, like this:

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'crate.gif' );
var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );
```

I have "crate.gif" in my local folder, but it does not appear on the box.

I am expected to either run a web server, or I can use a data url, because local image loading does not work, as re-iterated by the developer.

- Running a web server is an unacceptable work-around and will *not* be considered.
- I may be willing to do the chore of converting every single image into Base64, but I don't know how to integrate that solution.

I realize the image may not be displaying because it hasn't loaded before being called. What is the easiest way to load an image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-origin image load denied on a local image with THREE.js on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076816/cross-origin-image-load-denied-on-a-local-image-with-three-js-on-chrome)

Comment: Question has been asked multiple times before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845141/how-to-display-a-locally-selected-image-in-three-js

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: @Marquizzo no, running a server is explicitly forbidden in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It **is** just as easy as using a Data URI in place of an image filename, *if it's done right*:

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32);
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA--(truncated-for-example)--BAgEASABIAAD" );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to load an image as a texture is with a require and using a relative path of your image:

I'm using React and works for me.

```
const textureImage = require('../assets/images/image.png');
const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(textureImage);
const geometry = geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: This depends on node.js, therefore is not a valid answer

Comment: I understand, but I hope this answer helps other people with this problem on node.js or react.